# Does size of a javascript object/array in affect time to access or change a piece of data in the object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object

I would like to know if adding or accessing data in a large object/array is slower than in a small object/array.

For example if I have an object/array with 50000 items and wanted to change or access it, would it be slower than a smaller object/array with only 500 items?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you access it in constant time. it doesnt matter

Comment: if you access it by index, its the same speed. If you access it by looping over it, it is slower the more data it loops over.

Comment: Yes, it's slower in theory to work with larger objects, but by a so small amount that you don't need to concern yourself with it. In practice, treat it as constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Accessing* one array element or object property will take about the same time regardless of size.

*Adding* data will differ depending on whether we're talking about an array or a non-array object, and where and how you add the data.

I can't speak to the specifics of any particular JavaScript engine, but generally variable length array implementations have two different lengths: the *allocated* length and the *current* length. The `array.length` property you see in JavaScript is the *current* length, but the memory allocated for the array is often larger than that. For example, an array of 100 elements may actually allocate enough room for 128 elements.

So when you call `array.push()`, there may already be extra room in the array data. This case is very fast. The code only needs to increment `.length` and store the new array element.

This is the reason for allocating room for more elements than the current length: to avoid having to reallocate memory on every `.push()`.

However, once the current length reaches the allocated length, the next `.push()` needs to *reallocate* the entire array and usually has to copy all of the previous array elements to the new memory location. That makes this particular `.push()` much slower. However, subsequent `.push()` calls will be fast, until the current length again reaches the allocated length.

In some cases the reallocation may happen in place - there may happen to be unallocated space immediately after the end of the array so it can expand without copying - but that is a less common case.

The exact strategy for this reallocation varies: the engine may double the allocated array length as soon as it needs to reallocate, or multiply the length by 1.5, or whatever it chooses.

Now what if you use `array.unshift()` or `array.splice()` to insert one or more elements at or near the *beginning* of the array? In this case, even if the allocated array length has room for the extra elements, the speed will depend on the current array length because all existing elements after the insertion point must be moved in memory.

This is less of a factor for a non-array object. Adding a new property, whatever its key value, does not require moving all the existing properties around. It may be somewhat slower for an object with a large number of properties, but not in the same way as adding elements near the beginning of an array. Objects are implemented with a hash table or similar data structure. The engine may decide to reallocate the hash table to make it larger when there are too many hash collisions (keys that map to the same hash value), but this will be about the same whatever key value you are adding. Whether the key is "less than" or "greater than" any existing values just isn't relevant here.

If you have more specific questions we can kick them around further.

Answer (score -1):

If you need the *final* contents of an array to be in some specific sequence, then *by far* the fastest thing to do is to first assemble the array, in any sequence whatever, then *sort* the array into the final sequence that you need.

"Sorting," in any modern language at all, is a so-called `O(log(n))` operation, which means that its worst-case performance is "on the order of" some *logarithm* of the number of elements – which is "pretty darned good."  If you then need to add more elements to the sorted-array, just add the elements to the end and then re-sort.

*N.B.:* "Data sets that are known to be sorted in a certain way" have been used with great success *literally* "before computers existed," in the days of punched cards.

Comment: OP didn't mention anything about order or sorting, did you mean to answer a different question?

Comment: No, sorting is `O(n log(n))`, and just adding elements and re-sorting is not always the best approach.